# How to make asymmetric JWT auth with passport-jwt?

Tags: javascript, express, jwt, passport.js

I'm stuck with this documentation. It says:

> secretOrKey is a string or buffer containing the secret (symmetric) or PEM-encoded public key (asymmetric) for verifying the token's signature.

I'm thinking like why I need to put the public key in `secret`? I need to encrypt the token with my private key and then decrypt all incoming requests with my public key (I've even readed this in JWT GitHub ReadMe, like you need to sign token with your PRIVATE key, not public). How it works with passport-jwt or express-jwt? It doesn't say anything about private key. Only about a public key. Where I have to use my private key in this case or these libraries have no support of asymmetric RS256 algorithm with jwt and I need to write my own middleware with original `jsonwebtoken` library?

Comment: Hello Monolink. I'm not downvoting your question but I cannot really understand what you want to know. Is this a theory question or a code question? Do you want to see how to register or login someone with jwt?

Comment: This is more about code. I want to know if I can make JWT auth with express-jwt or passport-jwt packages?

Comment: Please check this GitHub repo where you can find everything you might ever need to make a working JWT-based modern API auth system:
https://github.com/ZeldOcarina/natours-node-bootcamp